# How to make a 3d cube rotate in place

Tags: html, css

I have created a 3d cube using CSS, now i want to rotate that cube on my HTML page. My problem is the when the cube rotates, it also moves to the sides, i need it to stay in place and rotate.

i've tried changing the posistion of my div to relative, which scattered the cube sides and still made it rotate to the sides.
I believe the problem has something to do with the transform-origin, however no matter how i change the values it doesn't help.

```css
.spinner div {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.spinner .face1 {
  transform: translateZ(150px);
  background-color: blue;
}

.spinner .face2 {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: rgb(184, 187, 31);
}

.spinner .face3 {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: green;
}

.spinner .face4 {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: red;
}

.spinner {
  animation: spincube 6s infinite;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}

.center-screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: top;
  align-items: top;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}

@keyframes spincube {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="center-screen">
    <div class="spinner">
      <div class="face1">1</div>
      <div class="face2">2</div>
      <div class="face3">3</div>
      <div class="face4">4</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

as described i expected the cube to stay in place but it slides out to the side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would re adjust the transformation like below to make sure the slides are around the center of the main element which is an empty element.

Note the use of `translateX` to achieve the needed effect.

```css
.spinner div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.spinner .face1 {
  transform: translateZ(50px) translateX(-50%);
  background-color: blue;
}

.spinner .face2 {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  background-color: rgb(184, 187, 31);
}

.spinner .face3 {
  transform: translateZ(-50px) translateX(-50%) rotateY(180deg) ;
  background-color: green;
}

.spinner .face4 {
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(-90deg);
  background-color: red;
}

.spinner {
  animation: spincube 6s infinite;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: inline-block; /* This is important !!*/
  outline: 5px solid red; /* to illustrate */
}

.center-screen {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

@keyframes spincube {
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="center-screen">
  <div class="spinner">
    <div class="face1">1</div>
    <div class="face2">2</div>
    <div class="face3">3</div>
    <div class="face4">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also rely on `left` to handle this:

```css
.spinner div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  left:-50px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.spinner .face1 {
  transform: translateZ(50px);
  background-color: blue;
}

.spinner .face2 {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  background-color: rgb(184, 187, 31);
  left:0;
}

.spinner .face3 {
  transform: translateZ(-50px) rotateY(180deg) ;
  background-color: green;
}

.spinner .face4 {
  transform:rotateY(-90deg);
  background-color: red;
  left:-100px;
}

.spinner {
  animation: spincube 6s infinite;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: inline-block; /* This is important !!*/
  outline: 5px solid red; /* to illustrate */
  position:relative;
}

.center-screen {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

@keyframes spincube {
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="center-screen">
  <div class="spinner">
    <div class="face1">1</div>
    <div class="face2">2</div>
    <div class="face3">3</div>
    <div class="face4">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:
Credits: https://codepen.io/bcgwebdesign/pen/gRXxxR?editors=0100

Tip: There are a lot of demos of this kind on Codepen

```css
/* keyframes for rotating animation */
@-webkit-keyframes spinX {
  from { transform: rotateY(0); }
  to   { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinBoth {
  from { transform: rotateY(0) rotateX(0); }
  to   { transform: rotateY(360deg) rotateX(0deg) ; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinY {
  from { transform: rotateX(0); }
  to   { transform: rotateX(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes recolor {
  0% { background: rgba(0,255,0,0.1); }
  33%   { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.1); }
  66%   { background: rgba(0,0,255,0.1); }
}

/* scene wrapper */

.wrapper{
  height: 300px;
  margin-top:0;
  position:relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  perspective-origin: 50% -50px;
}

/* cube wrapper */
.cube {
  position: relative;
  margin: 200px auto;
  width: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: spinBoth 5s infinite ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

/* outer cube */
b {
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:block;
  background:rgba(255,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:200px;
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  font-family:sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
b.back{
  transform: translateY(-100px) translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
}
b.right{
  transform:translateY(-100px) rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px);
  transform-origin: top right;
}
b.left{
  transform:translateY(-100px)rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
  transform-origin: center left;
}
b.top{
  transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px) translateZ(-100px);
  transform-origin: top center;
}
b.bottom{
  transform:rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px) translateZ(100px);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
b.front{
  transform: translateZ(100px) translateY(-100px);
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="cube">
           <b class="front">front</b>
           <b class="back">back</b>
           <b class="top">top</b>
           <b class="bottom">bottom</b>
           <b class="left">left</b>
           <b class="right">right</b>
      </div>
    </div>
```